Incorrect position and numbering of tables after using longtable
I am having two tables (A&B) and one longtable (C) in my document and I want to order and number them as:
Table 1 (table A)
Table 2 (table B)
Table 3 (longtable C)
but currently the order and numbering is
Table 1 (longtable C)
Table 2 (table A)
Table 3 (table B)
I tried to write \addtocounter{table}{-1} after the longtable, but now it became:
Table 1 (longtable C)
Table 1 (table A)
Table 2 (table B)
Your help will be much appreciated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

well table A and B are floats, the longtable is not.  So you will have to be careful how you place them in the code. You could use placeins and its \FloatBarrier command to force the flushout of the floats before the longtable starts.

often you simply need to put \clearpage  before the longtable
